# O que significa a tralha ao lado de um elemento (html/xml...)?

Tags: html, html5, xml, html-tags

Numa marcação HTML, encontrei uma tag que eu ainda não havia visto.

Pesquisei, mas não encontrei nada que me ajudasse.

Ela está aninhando uma tag `<li>` e o código (alterado) está assim:

```
<ul class="list-tabs-navigation list-inline">
    <#list (pageRender.getInstancesIds("SlotB"))! as id>
        <li class="tab-navigation-items state-default">
            <a class="item-navigation-link" href="#">qualquer 1</a>
        </li>
    </#list>
</ul>
```

Qual a função de `<#list`?

Comment: Framework da TOTVS? http://tdn.totvs.com/pages/releaseview.action?pageId=113803693

Comment: É do Apache Freemaker [<#list>](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_directive_list.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essa tag não é padrão do **HTML**, ela foi criada utilizando componentes de marcação como a documentação do [FreeMarker](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/dgui_template_directives.html) explica.

**Respondendo sua pergunta:**

Você usa tags FTL para chamar diretivas . No exemplo, você chamou a *listdiretiva*. Sintaticamente você fez isso com duas tags: *`<#list (pageRender.getInstancesIds("SlotB"))! as id>`* e *`</#list>`*.

Existem dois tipos de tags FTL:

Start-tag: `<#directivename parameters>`

Tag final: `</#directivename>`

Isso é semelhante à sintaxe HTML ou XML, exceto pelo nome da tag que começa com #. Se a diretiva não tiver conteúdo aninhado (conteúdo entre a tag inicial e a tag final), você deverá usar a tag inicial sem tag final. Por exemplo, você escreve `<#if something>...</#if>`, mas assim `<#include something>` o FreeMarker sabe que a diretiva `include` não pode ter um conteúdo aninhado.

O formato dos *parameters* depende do *directivename*.

Na verdade, existem dois tipos de diretivas: [diretivas predefinidas](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/gloss.html#gloss.predefinedDirective) e [diretivas definidas pelo usuário](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/gloss.html#gloss.userDefinedDirective) . Para diretivas definidas pelo usuário, você usa `@` em vez de `#`, por exemplo `<@mydirective parameters>...</@mydirective>` . Outra diferença é que, se a diretiva não tiver conteúdo aninhado, você deve usar uma tag como `<@mydirective parameters />`, da mesma forma que em XML (por exemplo `<img ... />`).

Tags **FTL**, como tags **HTML**, devem ser aninhadas corretamente. Portanto, o código abaixo está errado, pois a *ifdiretiva* está dentro e fora do conteúdo aninhado da list diretiva:

```
<ul>
<#list animals as animal>
  <li>${animal.name} for ${animal.price} Euros
  <#if user == "Big Joe">
     (except for you)
</#list> <#-- WRONG! The "if" has to be closed first. -->
</#if>
</ul>
```

---

**Referências em:**

- [Construindo Layouts Fluid](http://tdn.totvs.com/pages/releaseview.action?pageId=113803693#Constru%C3%A7%C3%A3odecomponentesWCMnoFluigStudio-Cria%C3%A7%C3%A3odeLayout)
- [Usando modelos FreeMarker](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/FreeMarker/article.html)
- [Todas as especificações e como utilizar](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/dgui_template_directives.html)

Answer (score 4):

Dentro da [especificação do HTML](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/) não consta isto, então não é algo que qualquer navegador deva reconhecer, e até onde eu sei nenhum reconhece.

Isto provavelmente é algo inserido como sintaxe específica para alguma ferramenta. Pode ser algo que seja interpretado no *backend* antes de enviar para o *browser* ou pode ser até mesmo algo que algum *framework* de (*frontend*  entende e sabe o que fazer manipulando o DOM, o que eu acho uma solução terrível porque até para isso tem especificação e não é assim que faz.

Fora isto, pode ser puro erro de sintaxe de alguém, alguma corrupção, pode ser que seja uma espécie de comentário que a pessoa usou pra não considerar aquilo. Não dá para saber porque a pergunta não tem contexto. Mas o mais provável é o anterior, até pelo complemento de sintaxe dele. Veja que em uso comum nem é considerado HTML

```html
<ul class="list-tabs-navigation list-inline">
    <#list>
        <li class="tab-navigation-items state-default">
            <a class="item-navigation-link" href="#">qualquer 1</a>
        </li>
    </#list>
</ul>
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/HTML_CSS/List.html).

Parece que o Laércio Lopes deu o contexto e mostra que é um *framework* de *backend* mesmo. Ele interpretará e fará algo com o código antes de mandar para o *browser* que receberá algo limpo e simples.